# react-native-fbsdk for Windows app

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk for my React Native Project.

It is working fine for Android and iOS , as I followed the steps mentioned on their official site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native

But, there are no resources for fbsdk Windows integration.

Is it possible to integrate fbsdk with Windows react-native app ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what features you want, we ported some of the react-native-fbsdk features for the F8 Developer Conference app here:

https://github.com/ReactWindows/f8app/tree/master/windows/F8v2/FBSDK

And we leveraged a shared wrapper around the FB SDK that encapsulated the slight differences in the API:

https://github.com/ReactWindows/f8app/blob/master/js/FacebookSDK.js